# Regression using Gam gives an unexpected shape

Tags: r, regression, generalized-additive-model, splines

I am running a regression using the gam function.

```
fit <- gam(y~ s(x))
```

The smoothing parameter used is the default one and number of knots are kept to be determined automatically.

The plot below shows the scatter plot for variable x and the smoothed curve. I fail to understand as why is there an upward trend in the smoothed curve when there is no such pattern seen in the scatter plot. Please advice where am I going wrong. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You should create a hexbin plot or something similar in order to see how many points are behind the overplotting.